# CSS Styles not correctly working in IE 11 on Windows 8

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer

So, to say the least, I do not understand IE. As a web designer/(slight)developer that is and will always be my achilles heel.

I've launched a website but haven't advertised it yet, and just as I check on windows 8 IE 11, see that it's falling apart.

I know certain CSS3 styles aren't accepted throughout all the browsers but I figured if it worked in IE 11 on Windows 7 then it would be fine? However a few styles on the the website are quite the opposite on IE 11 on Windows 8. So whats the difference?

This is a particualr part of the site I had a feeling would cause an issue so I'll use this one as an example.

```
#ez-home-top-1:before {
    background: url("http://mywebsite.com/IMAGES/banner-bg-bottom.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1em solid #000;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 65px;
    left: -9000px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9000px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

On Window 7 in IE 11 this is what it looks like

[image]

On Window 8 in IE 11 this is what it looks like

[image]

Any suggestion, article or advice as to how to work with this is very much appreciated!

Comment: why are you doing that? simply apply the bg to the div and that's it, do not abuse of pseudo-elements unless really needed, or face the consequences (like this)

Comment: I had to absolutely position my main slideshow under the top elements (best way to do it for responsive methods) and the only way to correctly set that bottom image to the left and right was to use :before. Plus, I didn't think that was so bad seeming as it actually works in browsers, just for some reason, not in Windows 8.

Comment: Is Compatibility View turned on in the Win 8 machine? This isn't a minor nuance in interpreting standards or lack of support for a CSS3 property (as might be expected); the Win 8 version is completely broken.

Comment: Hey Tim, if you want to "answer" the question. I found the compatibility mode and turned it off. It works fine now.

Comment: @kia4567 how did you fix this?  Was it some OS configuration in your windows 8? or a change in your website code which you made?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ It was a configuration in IE! I'll take a look at where I found it and let you know later when I can jump on a PC.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is because you are using rgba(0,0,0,0). While in modern browsers this is fully transparent black so it then uses your image as a backgronud, ie8 and below see this as fully black. Try removing that part.

Comment: -1 while true, the question states "IE 11" at least 4 times. So IE 8 behavior isn't (directly, at least) the answer.

Comment: Completely understandable about the rgba. I was aware of the solid colour in some browsers. The drastic difference between the same browser on a different operating systems is my main qualm.

Comment: I would double check things like Doctype and Compatibility Mode.